# "Error opening CA private key" on Windows

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I am running on **Windows Server 2003**, and installed **Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.1i Light**

No matter what guide I follow to set it up, I always end up with the following error when trying to actually sign a certificate

`openssl ca -in my.csr -out my.cert.pem`

> Using configuration from C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg
>   Loading 'screen' into random state - done
>   Error opening CA private key ./myCA/private/myCA.key.pem
>   1776:error:02001003:system library:fopen:**No such process:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:398:fopen('./myCA/private/myCA.key.pem','rb')**
>   1776:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:400:
>   unable to load CA private key

The paths to the key exist (triple and quadruple checked).
However I don't know what is this `.\crypto\` that it's looking for.

I did not have this issue using pre-installed Mac OS's `openssl`, so makes me think there is an environment pre-requisite that is missing...

Comment: The path to `myCA.key.pem` is relative so it depends from which directory you run openssl. If your working directory is `C:/OpenSSL-Win64/bin/` then the path to private key of CA should be `C:/OpenSSL-Win64/bin/myCA/private/myCA.key.pem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to `myCA.key.pem` is relative so it depends from which directory you run openssl. If your working directory is `C:/OpenSSL-Win64/bin/` then the path to private key of CA should be `C:/OpenSSL-Win64/bin/myCA/private/myCA.key.pem`