# Can't get QSslSocket to work

Tags: c++, qt, ssl

I'm attempting to write a simple client-server application in Qt that would comunicate over SSL. I tried using QSslSockets, but I keep having variuos problems.

Take a look at this:

Client:

```
#define dumpvar(x) qDebug()<<#x<<'='<<x

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSslSocket s;
    auto cert = QSslCertificate::fromPath("/home/piotrek/cert.pem");
    Q_ASSERT(!cert.isEmpty());
    s.setCaCertificates({cert});
    s.connectToHostEncrypted("localhost", 1234);
    qDebug()<<"waiting for encrypted";
    if (!s.waitForEncrypted(10000)){
        dumpvar(s.errorString());
        dumpvar(s.sslErrors());
        return 0;
    }

    qDebug()<<"client connected";
}
```

Server:

```
#define dumpvar(x) qDebug()<<#x<<'='<<x

class SslServer: public QTcpServer
{
    // QTcpServer interface
protected:
    void incomingConnection(qintptr handle) override
    {
        QSslSocket s;
        if (!s.setSocketDescriptor(handle)){
            dumpvar(s.errorString());
            return;
        }
        s.setLocalCertificate("/home/piotrek/cert.pem");
        s.setPrivateKey("/home/piotrek/pkey.pem", QSsl::Rsa, QSsl::Pem, "test");
        s.startServerEncryption();
        qDebug()<<"waiting for encrypted";
        if(!s.waitForEncrypted(10000)){
            dumpvar(s.errorString());
            dumpvar(s.sslErrors());
            return;
        }

        qDebug()<<"server encrypted";

        handleConnection(&s);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    SslServer s;

    s.listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1234);
    return a.exec();
}
```

The client prints:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
waiting for encrypted
<10 second pause>
s.errorString() = "Network operation timed out"
s.sslErrors() = ()
```

The server prints:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
waiting for encrypted
<10 second pause>
s.errorString() = "The remote host closed the connection"
s.sslErrors() = (
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which operating system, openssl version and Qt version are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, Qt 5.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation for the warnings is that `OpenSSL` in Ubuntu is compiled without insecure sslv2 but Qt 5.8 tries to load those functions in runtime. Qt uses only secure protocols by default so these warnings don't affect you unless you explicitly call [QSslSocket::setProtocol](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslsocket.html#setProtocol) with `QSsl::SslV2` (which of course doesn't work with your openssl).

Obviously **something is wrong with your self-signed? certificate**. Also, connection would fail anyway with self-signed certificate unless hostname mismatch is ignored explicitly.

In case, you are using self-signed certificates you could re-generate them with the instructions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072668/openssl-sign-https-client-certificate-with-ca/32096337#32096337).

Please, find below the working code example. Tested on similar environment (*surprise!*) `Ubuntu 16.10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g 1 Mar 2016, Qt 5.8.0`.

### Server

```
class SslServer: public QTcpServer
{
    // QTcpServer interface
protected:
    void incomingConnection(qintptr handle) override
    {
        QSslSocket s;
        if (!s.setSocketDescriptor(handle)){
            dumpvar(s.errorString());
            return;
        }
        const QString serverCertPath("/path/to/server1.pem");
        const QString serverKeyPath("/path/to/server1.key");
        s.setLocalCertificate(serverCertPath);
        s.setPrivateKey(serverKeyPath, QSsl::Rsa, QSsl::Pem, "test");
        s.startServerEncryption();
        qDebug()<<"waiting for encrypted";
        if(!s.waitForEncrypted(10000)){
            dumpvar(s.errorString());
            dumpvar(s.sslErrors());
            return;
        }
        qDebug()<<"server encrypted";
        s.write("Hello client");
        s.flush();
        s.waitForBytesWritten(3000);
        s.close();
    }
};
```

### Client

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSslSocket s;
    const QString rootCAPath("/path/to/rootCA.pem");
    auto rootCACert = QSslCertificate::fromPath(rootCAPath);
    Q_ASSERT(!rootCACert.isEmpty());
    s.setCaCertificates(rootCACert);

    // ignore SSL host name mismatch error for server certificate
    QList<QSslError> errorsToIgnore;
    const QString serverCertPath("/path/to/server1.pem");
    auto serverCert = QSslCertificate::fromPath(serverCertPath);
    Q_ASSERT(!serverCert.isEmpty());
    errorsToIgnore<<QSslError(QSslError::HostNameMismatch, serverCert.at(0));
    s.ignoreSslErrors(errorsToIgnore);

    s.connectToHostEncrypted("localhost", 1234);
    qDebug()<<"waiting for encrypted";
    if (!s.waitForEncrypted(10000)){
        dumpvar(s.errorString());
        dumpvar(s.sslErrors());
        return 0;
    }
    qDebug()<<"client connected";
    s.waitForReadyRead(3000);
    qDebug() << "Reading: " << s.bytesAvailable();
    qDebug() << s.readAll();
    s.close();
}
```

Server output:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
waiting for encrypted
server encrypted
```

Client output:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
waiting for encrypted
client connected
Reading:  12
"Hello client"
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

Comment: If something was wrong with the certificate, wouldn't I be getting a certificate reror instead of a timeout?

Comment: Can't say because I don't know how you generated csr, CA cert, cert and key. You can use openssl verify to check them all. I suggest you first generate a new set with the instructions pointed out and then if everything works well you know your certificate set was screwed and can investigate what went wrong with them.

Comment: You were right, the key was named key.pem instead of pkey.pem :/

Still, it's pretty shitty for Qt to not report that in any way.

Comment: That was actually a problem I had while trying to produce a short self contained example of another problem that I still have. Can you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115786/qsslsocket-times-out-when-waiting-for-data-but-qtcpsocket-does-not?